# How to add badge on top of Font Awesome symbol?

Tags: css, font-awesome, badge

I would like to add badge with some number (5, 10, 100) on top of the [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) symbol (`fa-envelope`). For example:

[image: the picture]

But, I can not understand how to put the badge on top of the symbol. My attempt is available here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/zxVhL/9/).

I would like to have it support Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This can be done with no additional mark-up, just a new class (which you would use anyway) and a pseudo element.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zxVhL/15/)**

**HTML**

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-5x fa-border icon-grey badge"></i>
```

**CSS**

```
*.icon-blue {color: #0088cc}
*.icon-grey {color: grey}
i {   
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position: relative;
}
.badge:after{
    content:"100";
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,255,1);
    height:2rem;
    top:1rem;
    right:1.5rem;
    width:2rem;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2rem;;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:white;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to move `content` out of css to html?

Comment: Not unless you go down the extra element route like a `<span>`  ALTHOUGH you could use a `data-attribute` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zxVhL/18/

Comment: This answer doesn't really work when the count is thousand or more.

Comment: Expanding on Paulie_D's comment and jsfiddle: When passing-in an argument from html with a data attribute (e.g. data-count), you can hide the badge with .badge[data-count="0"]:after{ display : none; }

Comment: For IE 11.0.900.18097 - The number was at the top of the badge when I expected it would be in the middle. I changed line-height on the pseudo element from rem to em and it worked. There is an ie bug on the subject: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/776744

Comment: For a bootstrap support you would have to change the class named badge because it is already used by the framework ...

Comment: It is **now** it wasn't when this answer was written.

Answer (score 49):

While @Paulie_D's answer is good, it doesn't work so well when you have a variable width container.

This solution works a lot better for that: http://codepen.io/johnstuif/pen/pvLgYp

HTML:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x has-badge" data-count="8,888,888">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-bell fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.fa-stack[data-count]:after{
  position:absolute;
  right:0%;
  top:1%;
  content: attr(data-count);
  font-size:30%;
  padding:.6em;
  border-radius:999px;
  line-height:.75em;
  color: white;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,.85);
  text-align:center;
  min-width:2em;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: This uses the built-in Font Awesome approach to stacking icons.

Answer (score 24):

Wrap the `fa-envelope` and the `span` containing the number in a `div` and make the wrapper div `position:relative` and the `span` `position:absolute`.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/k2VCK/)

HTML used

```
<div class="icon-wrapper">
   <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-5x fa-border icon-grey"></i>
   <span class="badge">100</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.icon-wrapper{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

*.icon-blue {color: #0088cc}
*.icon-grey {color: grey}
i {   
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.badge{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:-13px;
    right:-8px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Hope this might help you

Answer (score 14):

This seems to work, and it has a very minimal code to be added.

```css
.badge{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -60%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-bell fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  <span class="badge">17</span>
</span>
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-bell fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  <span class="badge">17</span>
</span>
<span class="fa-stack fa-1x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-bell fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  <span class="badge">17</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Best answer for bootstrap 4 and also margin-left: -15px;margin-top: -21px; worked best for me on all sizes

Answer (score 10):

http://jsfiddle.net/zxVhL/16/

By placing the badge inside the icon element I was able to position it relative to the bounds of the icon container. I did all the sizing using `em`s so that the size of the badge is relative to the size of the icon and this can be changed by simply changing the font-size in `.badge`

Comment: Nice solution: by adding a ::before and ::after of  '.\00a0' {space) and removing the 'width' attribute it also adjusts to any width badge.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the SVG + JS version of Font Awesome:

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/layering

> Layers are the new way to place icons and text visually on top of each other.

```
<span class="fa-layers fa-fw">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    <span class="fa-layers-counter" style="background:Tomato">1,419</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Font Awesome documentation](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/style/layer):

```html
<span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    <span class="fa-layers-counter" style="background:Tomato">1,419</span>
</span>
```