# Need help navbar notification button

Tags: html, css, button, notifications, navbar

i have a problem with my navbar notification button,
the button resize the navbar.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gewmi.png)

here is the code

```css
.badge-notify{
           background:red;
           position:relative;
           top: -20px;
           left: -35px;
        }
```

```html
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="#">

        
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-link">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
          </button>
          <span class="badge badge-notify">3</span>
        

        </a></li>
```

i dont know if a css problem or what, the button creates a blank space on navbar.

posibily the problem is

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735740/how-to-add-badge-on-top-of-font-awesome-symbol/22736017#22736017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, buttons inside links are invalid HTML so either use just a link or just a button...not both.

You need to put the second span **inside** the button (or link) and the position it absolutely.

```css
.btn-link {
  position: relative;
}

.badge-notify {
  background: red;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: -15px; /* adjust as required*/
  right: 5px; /* adjust as required*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
  <li>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-link">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
      <span class="badge badge-notify">3</span>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```